# How to connect an Arduino Uno with an ESP-01 to the Arduino IoT cloud?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-iot-cloud

I have been trying to connect to the Arduino IoT cloud using my Arduino Uno and an ESP-01.

The Arduino IoT cloud does not recognize my device as genuine. Hence, I've been trying to create a `thing` and connecting it as a third-party device. I have an ESP-01 WiFi module that I want to use to connect to the IoT cloud.

I tried the following connection:

```
Arduino ----> ESP-01  
3.3V  ------> 3v3  
3.3V  ------> EN(CH_PD)  
TX(1) ------> TX  
RX(0) ------> RX  
GND   ------> GND
```

I also tried to reverse the connections of the RX and TX pins. Still no success. I want to connect to the cloud and use some sensors to update the cloud variables. How do I do it? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Edit: I tried to upload the code that thd cloud editor provided and it throws and error saying:

```
fatal error: list: No such file or directory
 #include <list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino IoT Cloud doesn't support Arduino Uno, but it does support esp8266.

You have to do the communication with the IoT Cloud from a ESP-01 sketch with [esp8266 Arduino Core](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino?tab=readme-ov-file#installing-with-boards-manager). Then you can pass the values from/to a sketch in Uno over Serial.

There are ESP8266 development boards which can replace the Uno in many projects. Search for "Wemos D1 mini" or "NodeMCU" ESP8266 modules.

The ESP32 is even more capable MCU with WiFi and Arduino Core is available. It is too supported in Arduino Cloud and Arduino even has a new Nano ESP32 board.

Comment: I was able to connect to [Blynk](https://blynk.cloud/) using the same devices. It turns out that it is low-code platform and since I have a programming background, I was looking for a way to connect to the IoT cloud with the same configurations so that I could have more customization and flexibility. Thank you for your kind response. I will though give it a try with NodeMCU sometime soon.

Comment: @SauravGhimire Blynk has binary protocol and allows unsecure access

Comment: Can you suggest me with a better alternative? I am actually thinking of using the ESP 32 in my final project but till then, I will be using this setup with blynk(while learning and as a hobby). Thankyou!